# Why is the following bitshift operation not discarding the bit shifted to the left?

Tags: c#, bit-shift

Let's say I wrote the following :

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:X8}", (uint)1 << 31);
```

It returns `80000000` (as expected).

However, If I wrote :

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:X8}", (uint)1 << 32);
```

It returns `00000001`.

I would expect the "1" bit to be discarded and the result to be `00000000`.

Here is what [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#left-shift-operator-) says :

> The left-shift operation discards the high-order bits that are outside
>   the range of the result type and sets the low-order empty bit
>   positions to zero.

Indeed, if I wrote this :

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:X8}", (uint)0xFA << 28);
```

It returns `A0000000` (`F` is discarded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From that same [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#shift-count-of-the-shift-operators):

> For the `x << count` and `x >> count` expressions, the actual shift count depends on the type of x as follows:
>
> - If the type of `x` is int or uint, the shift count is defined by the low-order five bits of the right-hand operand. That is, the shift count is computed from `count & 0x1F` (or `count & 0b_1_1111`).

`32 & 0x1F` is `0`.

This "gotcha" is bad enough that former C# design team member Eric Lippert named it [the 8th worst C# feature](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867).

Comment: It's so goofy. It was a bad design in C, and it's weird that we're still stuck with it four decades later.